# Get name of document open in application on OSX (python)

Tags: python, ios, xcode, macos, plist

Using psutil module I retrieve a list of running applications, from there I check for open '.plist' files for those applications. Then I read the '.plist' files to get the title('NSTitle') of document/s currently open in the application.

Is there any better/ optimized way to accomplish this same task?

```
import psutil
import os
import plistlib


def check_files(application):
    plist_original_path = ""

    while True:
        for i in psutil.process_iter():
            try:
                if application in i.name():
                    for j in i.open_files():
                        if ".plist" in j.path:
                            plist_original_path = j.path

            except psutil.ZombieProcess:
                continue
            except psutil.NoSuchProcess:
                continue

        try:
            with open(plist_original_path, 'rb') as plist:
                read_plist = plistlib.load(plist)

            for i in read_plist:
                try:
                    title = i["NSTitle"]
                    print(title)
                except:
                    pass

        except FileNotFoundError:
            pass

check_files("Excel")
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find a better way using applescript with python.

```
import subprocess
import time


x = ''
while 1:
    time.sleep(1)

    with open('/Link/to/folder/app_script.txt', 'rb') as appscript:
        x = appscript.read()

    p = subprocess.Popen(['osascript', '-'], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    stdout, stderr = p.communicate(x)

    x = stdout.split(b',')

    print(x[0].decode().strip())
    print(x[1].decode().strip())
    print()
```